# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small error when processing multibyte characters

Tags: plsql

When I try to process a input string which contains a German Characters(Multibhyte characters) the program fails with ORA-06502 error.

The procedure parses input string which is a row in a CSV and each column value of the csv are added to a list and returned.

**Input String :**

> SIPCORE1000;SKYGUIDE, Société Anonyme Suisse pour les Services;Any2Any;Yes;SSM;No;None;6730:14892466;;109

**Procedure :**

```
 PROCEDURE ParseCSV(
        i_csvline IN VARCHAR2,
        i_Delimiter   IN            VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';',
        i_Enclosed IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '"',
        o_ColumnValueList OUT dimension.NAMELIST )
    IS 
      --
      CARRIAGE_RETURN CONSTANT CHAR(1) := chr(13);
      LINE_FEED       CONSTANT CHAR(1) := chr(10);
      --
      l_char           CHAR(1);
      l_lookahead      CHAR(1);
      l_pos            NUMBER          := 0;
      l_columnValue          VARCHAR2(32767) := NULL;
      l_columnValue_complete BOOLEAN         := false;
      l_line_complete  BOOLEAN         := false;
      l_new_column      BOOLEAN         := true;
      l_enclosed       BOOLEAN         := false;
      v_namelist dimension.NAMELIST :=dimension.NAMELIST();
      v_lastchar        VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN 
      SELECT SUBSTR(i_csvline,-1) INTO v_lastchar FROM dual;
      LOOP
        -- increment postion index
        l_pos := l_pos + 1;
        -- get the next character from input CSV line
        l_char := dbms_lob.substr( i_csvline, 1, l_pos);

        -- Exit when no more characters to process
        EXIT WHEN l_char IS NULL OR l_pos > dbms_lob.getLength( i_csvline );

        -- If the first character of new token is optionally enclosed character 
        -- note that and skip it and get the next character
        IF l_new_column AND l_char = i_Enclosed THEN
          l_enclosed             := true;
          l_pos                  := l_pos + 1;
          l_char                 := dbms_lob.substr( i_csvline, 1, l_pos);
        END IF;
        l_new_column := false;

        -- get the lookahead character
        l_lookahead := dbms_lob.substr( i_csvline, 1, l_pos+1 );

        -- Inspect the character (and lookahead) to determine what to do
        IF l_char             = i_Enclosed AND l_enclosed THEN
          IF l_lookahead      = i_Enclosed THEN
            l_pos            := l_pos + 1;
            l_columnValue          := l_columnValue || l_lookahead;
          elsif l_lookahead   = i_Delimiter THEN
            l_pos            := l_pos + 1;
            l_columnValue_complete := true;
          ELSE
            l_enclosed := false;
          END IF;
        elsif l_char IN ( CARRIAGE_RETURN, LINE_FEED ) AND NOT l_enclosed THEN
          l_columnValue_complete := true;
          l_line_complete  := true;
          IF l_lookahead  IN ( CARRIAGE_RETURN, LINE_FEED ) THEN
            l_pos := l_pos + 1;
          END IF;
        elsif l_char        = i_Delimiter AND NOT l_enclosed THEN
          l_columnValue_complete := true;
        elsif l_pos         = dbms_lob.getLength( i_csvline ) THEN
          l_columnValue          := l_columnValue || l_char;
          l_columnValue_complete := true;
          l_line_complete  := true;
        ELSE
          l_columnValue := l_columnValue || l_char;
        END IF;
        -- process a new token
        IF l_columnValue_complete THEN
          v_namelist.EXTEND;
          v_namelist(v_namelist.LAST):=l_columnValue;
          l_columnValue                    := NULL;
          l_enclosed                 := false;
          l_new_column                := true;
          l_columnValue_complete           := false;
        END IF;
        IF l_line_complete THEN
          l_line_complete := false;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      IF v_lastchar=i_Delimiter
      THEN
          v_namelist.EXTEND;
          v_namelist(v_namelist.LAST):=NULL;
      END IF; 
      o_ColumnValueList:=v_namelist;
    END ParseCSV;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `dimension` object as well

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "NAMELIST"    AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (200);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are multi byte encoding characters involved (In my case German Characters) then the variable that holds these characters should be VARCHAR2 and have size at least 2. I've defined the variable type as VARCHAR2 and size as 10. Now the procedure works as expected.